# This is not [pyth]on

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

**What can be done to reduce misuse of the [pyth] tag?**

The [pyth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyth) tag is intended for questions relating to the esoteric language [Pyth](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pyth). The tag was created in 2017 and has one question. That does not mean it has not been used. Lots of questions have been created with the [pyth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyth) tag. I don't know how many, because every one of them has been a Python question wrongly tagged. When these questions come in, someone checks them and fixes the tags.

For practical purposes, the [pyth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyth) tag's only use since its creation (apart from the one question it was created for) has been to mean "this Python question needs its tags fixing".

The first sentence of the usage guidance for the [pyth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyth) tag says that it is NOT the tag for Python questions. Obviously people do not read the usage guidance.

What I would like is to reduce the amount of misuse of the [pyth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyth) tag, each of which creates a problem that someone has to notice and fix.

Options:

1. Delete the tag. That is undesirable, because if it were being used correctly, it would be a valid tag for SO. (I'm pretty sure this one is out.)
2. Rename the tag something that is less likely to be mistaken for [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). Like [esoteric-pyth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esoteric-pyth). Or something better.
3. The tag remains as it is, but the behaviour of the tag GUI is changed to stop suggesting it to people, because it is never what they mean. I imagine this kind of change is impracticable.
4. I drop this, and the use of the [pyth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyth) tag continues as it has done, because tags are misused all the time, and this instance is not important enough to do something about.

Any other options, or opinions?

Comment: With respect to point 3, the only time [tag:pyth] is [recommended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8Xtx.gif) is when "pyth" is in the tag box; the suggestions there can't really be "fixed", as it's more a case of the OP just not paying attention at all...

Comment: @Larnu Then I guess people must be typing the first four letters of `python`, seeing any result at all (even one that says "This is NOT the Python tag" underneath it) and saying to themselves "A tag. Good. That will do."

Comment: More likely folks just start typing and hit enter when they see the recommended box pop up with [python] in it.   And then never notice they made a mistake because magical editor elves fix it for them.

Comment: Though they could have stopped at "py" then @DanielF ;)

Comment: *"and saying to themselves "A tag. Good. That will do.""* Unfortunately many of us know far too well that some users really do seem to have that mentality. The alternative (which is just as bad) is when they do things like "I'm writing a question about java. I better tag every thing java based! [tag:java], [tag:javascript], [tag:jscript], [tag:jdbc]" As users, we just have to "fix" their inappropriate tags and possibly (gently) remind them not the abuse the tag system.

Comment: Most folks working in `python` have worked with at least half a dozen packages that start with `py`, but point taken.

Comment: Concerning a possible new name for the tag, maybe `pyth-code-golf`is clearer.

Comment: @Damien Yes. `code-golf-pyth` is less likely to get accidentally matched while typing `python`.

Comment: @khelwood Effectively. However, in both cases, the error is obvious and should be rapidly corrected. That said, both look good for me.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a possible query to show how many questions were edited from `pyth` to `python` (might be effective to show the severity of the issue as well)?

Comment: I would think `pyth-lang` might work. It follows the pattern of some other languages out there (`slim-lang`, `crystal-lang`, `q-lang`). But then again, even better would be `pyth-the-language-not-python` :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey that's quite optimistic to think `pyth-the-language-not-python` would stop the users from abusing it.  But if it works, we can rename `C#` to `C#-is-not-C-or-C++`

Comment: @jps And `javascript-has-nothing-to-do-with-java`

Comment: This question is way too [pith]y

Comment: @Damien `pyth-code-golf` is clear to those who understand what both `pyth` and `code-golf` are. I think OP's recommendation of `esoteric-pyth` would best prevent misuse. And don't add a `pyth` synonym!

Comment: @MonkeyZeus As a C++ user, I find Python quite esoteric already! :) In addition, the term `esoteric-pyth` might look provocative to Python lovers ... Not sure it will be enough to avoid mistakes. At least the term *code-golf* is known by `pyth` users, and Python beginners might be frightened by the unknown term `pyth-code-golf`

Comment: @Damien I thought it's been concluded that users don't pay attention to what they're doing so if `pyth-code-golf` is the first suggestion then they'll pick it...

Comment: But if the term is `pyth-code-golf` then it won't ever be the first suggestion when typing `python`, @MonkeyZeus (as [tag:python] is significantly more popular).

Comment: If there is exactly one valid question with the [tag:pyth] tag, maybe that tag doesn't need to exist?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Why not? It's on-topic and adequately scoped, and a tag being unpopular has never been a reason to get rid of it. What else would you tag that one question with?

Comment: Y'all don't like the tag name `pyth-is-not-python`?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery: The reason that the tag hasn't been auto-removed is because it keeps being added to questions that it shouldn't be added to. There's a tool that runs every month and removes tags that have been used only once and never again in the following 6 months: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272094/do-not-automatically-expire-single-use-tags-on-stack-overflow

Comment: I guess pyth got swallowed by the python. We could simply change the name.

Comment: @jps: What you never saw [tag:c] [tag:sharp] for C# questions? This annoys not one but two groups.

Comment: @Joshua LOL, indeed didn't see that one, but have seen several times `.net` `core`

Comment: 352 posts have been retagged from [pyth] to [python] in the past 3 years, which means around 1 post every 3 days

Comment: `pyth-lang` seems like a really good solution. You just need it to not be the first result for `pyth...` and I think it would meet that need.

Comment: AFAIR I created this tag on request by a lowrep user (the OP). I'm sorry about the mishaps that I didn't anticipate. renaming seems a good option

Comment: @BhargavRao Thank you for looking that up. On one hand 352 in three years sounds like less than I thought. On the other hand, it means the tag has a 99.7% miss rate.

Comment: @BhargavRao So presumably that does not include questions that had the [pyth] tag deleted without the [python] tag specifically being added...?

Comment: @khelwood yes..

Comment: I like @Damien's suggestion of `pyth-code-golf` better than `pyth-esolang`. I think someone seeing the term "code golf" is more likely to think "I don't know what that is but I can tell it isn't what I want" than if they see something more esoteric like...well "esolang".

Comment: Missed the opportunity for "_This is not the [pyth]on tag you are looking for_"

Answer (score 49, accepted):

A couple of people have [suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402961/this-is-not-python/402989#comment808897_402961) renaming the tag to **[pyth-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyth-lang)**.

Although it still starts with the first four characters of `python`, presumably the tag GUI would not suggest it any more unless people get as far as `pyth-`, which hopefully is much less frequent than people typing `pyth` and then hitting enter.

It also seems less intrusive than the other suggestions of [esoteric-pyth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esoteric-pyth) etc.

---

As of 21 Nov 2020, the tag has been renamed [pyth-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyth-lang).

Comment: As an additional suggestion (not enough to warrant its own answer, surely), how about `esolang-pyth`? I’d prefer that to `esoteric-pyth`.

Comment: How about renaming to `python-on`. :D

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't like that idea because Pyth does not itself state anything about being esoteric. It does, however, describe itself as a golfing language.

Comment: `pyth-lang` would seemly obviously have the same problems "Oh pyth-lang that is for the python language which is what I want!"

Comment: @eric It would only have some of the same problems, because a user typing into the tag field does not have to type `pyth-lang` in order to type `python`.

Comment: @TylerH IMHO, golfing languages are a true subset of esoteric languages.

Comment: @KonradRudolph well technically, J boasts itself as being a serious language, but it is a golflang nevertheless. APL, for exactly the same reason.

Comment: @eric Renaming to `pyth-lang` (or in fact renaming it at all) would seem to solve the main problem... Currently when you type "pyth" exactly the `pyth` tag jumps to the #1 position from nowhere (because it's an _exact match_), otherwise it's not suggested at all. `python` tag drops to #2 for this one search only. If the tag is renamed with a suffix then there will be no exact match whilst typing "pyth" and the tag won't jump to the top (but still hopefully be in the top 6). And the "correct" `python` tag will remain at #1 position (as it is currently for "py", "pyt", "pytho" and "python").

Comment: "As of 21 Nov 2020, the tag has been renamed." - Although a "problem" now is the tag is difficult to find... it only appears in the search results once you type "pyth-l" (just the hyphen isn't sufficient; it appears to be ignored?). But this is really [a generic problem with how the tag search works](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387405/help-new-users-by-making-tagging-smarter),

Answer (score 29):

As this has not yet been suggested in an answer, I suggest its rename to [esolang-pyth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esolang-pyth).
This is so that it no longer conflicts with Python (due to the autocomplete) and the prefix is (IMHO) the most accurate representation of its purpose. This also makes sure that when a person is actually asking a Pyth question, they don't accidentally choose Python.

Comment: With only a single use, just retagging the question to esoteric-language and removing the tag altogether should do it.

Answer (score 17):

Rename it to [pyth-esolang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyth-esolang).

I like the suggestion [pyth-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyth-lang), but in my opinion some people may still think

> What does "pyth-lang" mean? I guess "pyth" means "python", and "lang" means "language"! Yes, it's a pretty easy riddle to guess! The two parts are just abbreviations!

or, in different words,

> Obviously here "lang" is an abbreviation for "language". Therefore, "pyth" should be an abbreviation for "python"!

To prevent this, let's use the "esolang" abbreviation, which will probably prevent this line of thinking.

BTW we have 1 question from 2015 tagged [fish-esolang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fish-esolang), which may be a weak indication that this syntax is reasonable.

Comment: `pyth-not-python`

Comment: Following the logic from the answer: *What does "pyth-esolang" mean? I guess "pyth" means "python", I don't know what "eso" is but "lang" probably means "language"! Yes, it's a pretty easy riddle to guess!*

Comment: Yes, that may happen too, but in my opinion less likely.

Comment: I think "esolang" suffers from the same problem [other attempts at clever compound words do](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385331/2370483)

Comment: That link is too meta, I didn't understand which problem you were talking about.

Comment: A `pyth-y-that-its-rarely-used`

Comment: I like this idea more than any suggested, but I still think the term "esolang" will not mean anything to many people.

Comment: `pyth-terse-python`, `pyth-short-python`, `pyth-to-python`. It seems to me that a good name should cause a python poster typing "pyth" to stop and say, "that tag sounds like something. idk what it is but it's probably not me".

Comment: @Machavity Esolang is an established word in the recreational programming community. After all, the [wiki](http://esolangs.org) is named after the term.

Answer (score 12):

What about changing the search algorithm to still favour extremely popular tags rather than obscure ones? I know [pyth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyth) is a perfect match for the "pyth" string, but we are talking about a tag with 1 question versus one with 1.5m questions.
How *probable* is that a user is indeed looking for [pyth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyth)?

Comment: And what if someone actually ***is*** looking for it? Doesn't it make sense that if they type `pyth`, the tag for that will appear (and not get hidden because of a more popular one)?

Comment: It could still appear in the search results, but not as the first result.

Comment: @DonaldDuck I am not sure if ***first*** has a meaning in the tag suggestion box... Would it be the tag to the right? to the left? top row? bottom? I would say that's a matter of personal orientation

Comment: Anyway counting on an *algorithm change* is quite a long-shot for a solution...

Comment: This is part of a much broader discussion. Tagging in general [needs to be smarter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387405/help-new-users-by-making-tagging-smarter)

Comment: The algorithm does favour popular tags to a degree, it's just that when there is an "exact match" the matched tag jumps to the top. This is the _only_ time the `pyth` tag appears at all in the tag search results (and the `python` tag is pushed down the #2 slot). For all other typing variations: "py", "pyt", "pytho" and "python" (naturally), the `python` tag appears as the #1 search result and so sign of `pyth`. It's quite incredulous how people seemingly _miss_ the `python` tag!?

Comment: @Tomerikoo The element in the top/left of the tag suggestion box is the first element in the _tabbing_ order, so is the first result that is selected when navigating using the keyboard.

Answer (score 9):

## Delete the tag

TL;DR While it's certainly *valid*, I believe it's highly unlikely to be actually used. If anything, maybe just remake it after a second relevant question exists.

I believe [pyth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyth) isn't all that useful considering that it has only had one question; if you are keeping this tag there's no reason not to add tags for all other esoteric languages that see considerable use (for example, ones on Code Golf Stack Exchange).

However, I do not believe it is likely to receive another question, mostly because it is a relatively obscure language intended for golfing, hence chances are most questions would be questions related to golfing, especially considering it doesn't have (or isn't intended to have) a standard library, heavily limiting the number of useful questions.

Comment: This... doesn't work really. Pyth actually is a programming language unto itself and questions about it need a tag. A better solution is a tag rename.

Comment: @Machavity Fair, but not sure how useful it is, considering it has had a use for a single question three years ago, and because of the confusion that is the reason for this question in the first place; I'm also not sure how I'd feel by using a nonstandard naming convention like in the other answers - I think a rename would be perfectly reasonable however I strongly *do not* think `procedural-pyth` is appropriate - Pyth is based on Python, so it is procedural just as Python is, so it is essentially a useless descriptor made just to avoid an exact match.

Comment: After looking at the discustion above though, I guess [tag:pyth-lang] is the best option, especially considering there is already plenty of inconsistency with main tags (? idk, the ones that are not synonyms) - for example [tag:twitter-bootstrap-3] vs [tag:bootstrap-4]

Comment: @Machavity A language which generated 1 single question in over 10 years of SO really does not need a tag. Deleting it would be harmless.

Comment: @Lundin Until someone recreates the tag. We could synonym [pyth] to [python] to prevent re-creation, but what of questions actually about Pyth then? We have a lot of single question tags. That doesn't automatically make them bad or worthless

Comment: @Machavity We can deal with that when it happens, 10 years from now...

Comment: Why don't we just move that single question to Code Golf Stack Exchange and remove the tag as you suggested?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the name of the tag could change to `procedural-pyth`

Comment: what makes it any more procedural than python?

Comment: @qwr The tag is procedurally generated through the means of discussion on meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Why the word "procedural"?  What's the justification for this specific choice of word?

Answer (score -41):

Propose renaming tag to `python-lang-pyth`

Keeping a separate `python` string in the tag should help clarify that it's distinct from Python (like a library tag [python-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-requests)), but is still related to it

Adding the `lang` string should help clarify that it's a language

Adding both should help push it to the back of the shortlist when a user types `pyth` in the tag box, while still allowing them (or more likely a reviewer) to find it as `lang-pyth`

If the search is still poor, consider using `lang-python-pyth` (or an alias for the one question?..)

Comment: *Keeping a separate python string in the tag should help clarify that it's distinct from Python* - I see it quite the other way around... If `python` is part of the tag, you would assume that the tag is related to Python, no? Also, this will probably make it come up with the suggestions for people typing `pytho...` and preserve the problem of careless users accepting any tag seems related

Comment: `codegolf-lang-pyth` seems more useful (insofar as pyth was created explicitly for use in code golf). I don't see what the `python` has to do with it -- we don't call the Python tag `c-lang-python` just because the canonical runtime for Python is implemented in C.

Comment: Downvoters do not realize that Pyth compiles to Python. It is not unreasonable to see it as part of the Python ecosystem. I upvoted this answer. @Tomerikoo Exactly, Pyth is related to Python, and this suggestion reflects that. Proposing a hierarchical naming scheme totally makes sense.

Comment: @janus taking into account that this tag currently has one sole question, and that the reason for this meta question is the fact that python questions are wrongly tagged with it - no, I don't think that python should be an explicit part of its name... (See the above comment by charles)

Comment: @Tomerikoo Why is it relevant how many questions are correctly tagged with pyth? The issue arose because questions were mistakenly tagged, a hierarchical naming scheme also solves this. A language is just an API with a syntax (in FP sometimes a DSL has no own syntax). So I don't see a fundamental difference between Pyth and Requests, and it is inconsistent to have one be prefixed with `python-` but the other not.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen This is not a technical problem, the problem isn't with whatever the implementation detail about Pyth is. This a UI/UX problem, people tag things wrongly all the time, and we fix that. The suggested alternative tag name is, no offense, horrible.